# Is the following infinite series convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Is the following series convergent?

$$\sum \frac{a^n}{(n+1)!}$$ where n goes from $n=0$ to infinity?

A hint would do. I do not know which test to use. I tried to use ratio test but

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apply the ratio test.  By the way, the series can be evaluated in terms of "elementary" functions.

Comment: Hint: multiply and divide by $a$. Does the series look familiar?

Comment: I did that, but I end up with $a/(n+2)$ which doesnt yield anything

Comment: @stochasticboy321 can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @JennieDurham He means write $\sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^{n}}{(n + 1)!} = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a}{a} \cdot \dfrac{a^{n}}{(n + 1)!} = \dfrac{1}{a} \sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \cdot \dfrac{a^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!}$, and now you should recognize this as $\dfrac{1}{a} e^{a}$.

Comment: @user46944 the set is convergent then. Thanks guys

Comment: Remember, in the ratio test, $a$ is fixed, and you have to take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Factorial growth will beat exponential growth nearly every time, thus the terms of the summation go to zero VERY fast (eventually), even if $a$ is a very large number.